# Disable by default jQuery click, on('click', etc. registering right clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a configuration option in jQuery basically to detect any click events, which are right click, and to only register left clicks in click or on handlers etc.?

Solutions should not require looking at e.which for every click handler of sorts then doing something else....

Comment: Maybe a `$(document).mousedown()` handler that checks `e.which`?

Comment: why do you want to do it? checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/contextmenu

Comment: Or `$(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); `

Comment: @ArunPJohny mostly by default, we want to be able to have all actions to default to working for left click only and not behave the same if someone right clicks

Comment: @chridam that only works if you bind everything to document...

Comment: then use contextmenu and return false

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/X3MeK/ uses `contextmenu` as @ArunPJohny stated, cancels the `oncontextmenu` event of the DOM element to disable the browser context menu, capture the `mousedown` event with jQuery, and then you can know in the event argument which button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
$("body").live('click', function(e) {
   if( (!$.browser.msie && e.button == 0) || ($.browser.msie && e.button == 1) ) {
       alert("Left Button");
   }
   else if(e.button == 2){
       alert("Right Button");
   }
});
```